# Position two absolute divs inside anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make a link fade effect in CSS. There are two divs inside `a` tag, the top one fades away on hover revealing the inner content.

However when the inside `div` has larger content it just overflows.
I realize this is due to the `position:absolute` and so its width is ignored by the parent `a`.

Is there a way the parent `a` could take the biggest width of the two `divs` ?

#### My code here:

The first link works as expected because the inner div has lesser content
The second link is the one describing this problem.

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #444;
}
a.fade {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
a.fade > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  text-align: center;
}
a.fade>div:first-child {
  position: absolute;
}
a.fade > div:last-child {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
a.fade:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
a.fade:hover > div:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fade">
  <div>Content inside</div>
  <div>This one fades</div>
</a>

<a href="#" class="fade">
  <div>Content inside</div>
  <div>This fades</div>
</a>
```

Any kind of workaround in `html` structure is appreciated as well, as long as the final thing is achieved.

Comment: When you add a position absolute, the element goes out of flow. So it is not possible to calculate the element size using pure CSS.

Comment: Yeah i already mentioned that in the question. I am asking if there is a way to achieve this effect

Comment: No. Not possible.

Comment: `Any kind of workaround in html structure is appreciated as well` ???

Comment: You get rid of the `absolute` Change it to `float` or something.

Comment: By any chance, Tamil theriyuma? `:)`

Comment: Theriyum :P !! No work around possible to achieve this effect ?

Comment: Instead of absolute positioning, You can use a negative margin on the second div and set a background-color on the first, pulling the second div behind the first.  Then you could transition opacity on the first div on hover. This will require setting a higher z-index on the second div than on the first.

Comment: Exactly @connexo Thats what i am asking!! But cant figure it out properly since length of string inside the `a` is unknown

Comment: @JonesVinothJoseph Now you can do it without any issues, add a `position: relative` to the parent and make the content to be absolutely positioned. `:D` This also aligns perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to achieve it using `absolute` positioning. But the same thing needs the parent to be relative one.

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #444;
}
a.fade {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
a.fade > span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  text-align: center;
}
a.fade > span:first-child {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
a.fade > span:last-child {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
a.fade:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(00, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
a.fade:hover > span:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fade">
  <span>Content inside</span>
  <span>This one fades</span>
</a>

<a href="#" class="fade">
  <span>Content inside</span>
  <span>This fades</span>
</a>
```

Comment: It was that simple, Did the `span` do the trick along with parent `relative` positioning? Because i tried your answer again with a `div` but dint work. I will go with `span` anyway

Comment: Does the relative positioning do the trick, or the `overflow: hidden;`?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you have to make `a { display: block; /* or inline-block */ }` for your HTML to stay valid. Otherwise `a` cannot contain block level elements.

Instead of absolute positioning, you can use a relative positioning and a negative bottom margin on the second div and set a background-color on the first, pulling the second div behind the first. Then you could transition opacity on the first div on hover. This will require setting a higher z-index on the second div than on the first.

```css
a {
  border: 20px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  }
a :first-child {
  background-color: #a00;
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  z-index: 3;
}

a :last-child {
  background-color: #0a0;
  margin-bottom: -1.2em;
  position: relative;
  top: -1.2em;
  z-index: 2;
}
a:hover :first-child {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div>Linktext</div>
  <div>Longer Link text on hover</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah thx, missed that one. It might be worth leaving it in the answer nonetheless because so many peoplee are unaware of that.